# Make two datatable row equal ex-first table have 10 rows and sec table have 5 row than in sec table 5 extra row should added in compare to first table

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I have two tables in one dataset and two tables have diff, columns and diff rows.

Now, what i want is to combine both table columns and insert row in the way that if both table have date(columns) by comparing both table date the result will be shown date wise but

For example :- if i have 2020-03-01 date in first table
Which have 5 rows and in sec table 2020-03-01 have 3 rows than in sec table two extra row with null values should be added in compare with first table.

I hope you understand my problem.

We have diff columns in two tables so what we have to do is if 1 table have 5 row with data in 5 rows and 2 table have 3 rows with data in 3 rows,now i want to add two extra row with null data to 2 table to make both table row same.

```
DataRow r;
        int rowIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataset1.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++, rowIndex++)
        {
            r = dt.NewRow();
            r["id"] = dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[i][0];
            r["kt"] = dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[i][1];
            r["billno"] = dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[i][2];
            r["jamaname"] = dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[i][3];
            r["jama"] = dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[i][4];
            r["makan"] = dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[i][5];
            r["vigli"] = dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[i][6];
            r["pani"] = dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[i][7];
            r["khaspani"] = dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[i][8];
            r["gatar"] = dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[i][9];
            r["safai"] = dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[i][10];
            r["anya"] = dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[i][11];
            r["open"] = dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[i][12];
            r["close"] = dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[i][13];
            r["date"] = dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[i][14];

            if (dataset1.Tables[1].Rows.Count > i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                r["id1"] = dataset1.Tables[1].Rows[i][0];
                r["kt1"] = dataset1.Tables[1].Rows[i][1];
                r["voucher"] = dataset1.Tables[1].Rows[i][2];
                r["cheque"] = dataset1.Tables[1].Rows[i][3];
                r["udharname"] = dataset1.Tables[1].Rows[i][4];
                r["khata"] = dataset1.Tables[1].Rows[i][5];
                r["remark"] = dataset1.Tables[1].Rows[i][6];
                r["udhar"] = dataset1.Tables[1].Rows[i][7];
                r["open1"] = dataset1.Tables[1].Rows[i][8];
                r["close1"] = dataset1.Tables[1].Rows[i][9];
                r["date1"] = dataset1.Tables[1].Rows[i][10];
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("i ---> " + i);
                r["id1"] = null;
                r["kt1"] = null;
                r["voucher"] = null;
                r["cheque"] = null;
                r["udharname"] = null;
                r["khata"] = null;
                r["remark"] = null;
                r["udhar"] = null;
                r["open1"] = null;
                r["close1"] = null;
                r["date1"] = null;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(r);
        }
```

Output :-
This image has two table but two tables rows are diff.

[image]

I want this kind of output:-
In this output two tables have same rows

[image: 2]

Comment: Take a look at DataTable Merge method. Please note, you don't need to use Pascal Space when you write questions

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you kindly, for the sake of better readability, write in normal style and only use capital letters on the beginning of a sentence and for names.